# Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called Error when I never use Invoke or BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, invoke

I'm new to C# and async programming so the solution to the problem I have might be simple (or not?!).

Here is the issue:

- I have an onClick function that create a new UIControl and add it to the current Form as a new tab.
- I had it run synchronously first and had no crash but the UI was blocked for a few second as the data provided to this Tab require a lots of calculations.
- I moved the onclick to async and added an await on the Control's datprocessing function but I now get the infamous:

> "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created".

```
private async void btnNewTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
            openFileDialog.Filter = "*.test";
            DialogResult dialogResult = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();

            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Display a basic loading Control while the other control is being prepared
                TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage("loading");
                LoadingControlPanel loadingPanel = new LoadingControlPanel();
                loadingPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                myTabPage.Controls.Add(loadingPanel);
                tabControl.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
                tabControl.SelectTab(myTabPage);

                //Load Data from files
                List<DataFile> result = await Task.Run(() => loadFiles(openFileDialog.FileNames));
                
                // create Control to display the data loaded
                MyTabControl newPanel = new MyTabControl();
                newPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

                // provide Data to new control (long processing)
                await Task.Run(() => newPanel.processData(result));

                // rename Tab, remove loading Control and display the tab with the processed Data
                myTabPage.Text = "Loaded";
                myTabPage.Controls.Remove(loadingPanel);
                myTabPage.Controls.Add(newPanel);
            }
        }
```

The crash always happen while I call the function "processData" but not alway at the same location. I have a few debug lines and they are not always the same processed.

The crash tells me the issue in on the line: "Application.Run(new FormMain());"

```
static void Main()
        {
            Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new FormMain());
        }
```

Here is the full stack trace:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException   HResult=0x80131604
> Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
> Source=System.Private.CoreLib   StackTrace:    at
> System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
> arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)    at
> System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry
> tme)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry
> tme)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg,
> IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
> Interop.User32.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.Interop.Mso.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(UIntPtr
> dwComponentID, msoloop uReason, Void* pvLoopData)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(msoloop
> reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(msoloop
> reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)    at
> Program.Main() in
> Program.cs:line
> 22
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> [External Code]
>
> Inner Exception 1: InvalidOperationException: Invoke or BeginInvoke
> cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been
> created.

What on earth am I doing wrong with all this?

Comment: Nothing is ever simple when async/await fails, Microsoft's attempts at making threading look easy invariably added five new undebuggable problems.  The stack trace is a mess, try to get ahead by forcing the debugger to stop at the exact moment the exception is thrown.  Debug > Windows > Exception Settings, tick CLR exceptions.

Comment: This doesn't change the error sadly :(

Comment: Put `newPanel.CreateControl();` after `MyTabControl newPanel = new MyTabControl();`

Comment: This did put me in the right direction. CreateControl() did not do the trick but newPanel.show() worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heart of the issue I had is that creating a Control will not automatically ensure the handler connected to it is created.

I changed my code to display the panel first (with a loading message) while the data is processed and displayed asynchronously.

As pointed by @Henk Holterman, the architecture can/should be changed and improved to avoid the need for this solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `Task.Run(() => newPanel.processData(result))`, that could only work when processData() didn't touch any UI stuff (but then why would it be part of a panel?)

You can only use Task.Run() on processing stuff and then load the results in the UI on the main thread.

See if you can make it look like:

```
//await Task.Run(() => newPanel.processData(result));
var data = await Task.Run(() => ProcessData(result));
newPanel.AcceptData(data);
```

LoadData and ProcessData() should preferably be part of some service class, not your Form. But that is about architecture, not about the direct problem.

Comment: I agree, the architecture need to be improved. The challenge is that the panel contain a few tabs that need the same Data and create a lots of UI elements from it.
I actually managed to resolve the issue by ensuring the handler was first created before running "newPanel.processData(result)".

Comment: As long as you realize you're on thin ice there.

Answer (score 0):

This code here

```
TabControl newPanel = new TabControl();
newPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

// provide Data to new control (long processing)
await Task.Run(() => newPanel.processData(result));
```

attempts to create a new TabControl, but never shows it, therefore it never has a window handle associated. This is completely independent of whether you do your data processing synchronously or asynchronously.

You seem to be missing some relevant code there as well, as `System.Windows.Forms.TabControl` does not have a `processData` method.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. TabControl is MyTabControl (I missed that detail). It has a function to process the data and display it to the user. As the Data Processing is slow, I only display it after the processing is done.
I tried checking IsHandleCreated and it returns false, how could I ensure/force it being created first?
Edit: Would the code not break all the time and instantly though in this case? The code sometimes works and sometimes not.

Comment: @Slamit You should probably not do the processing in an UI control at all. Separate the data from the display and use a separate, data-only class for the processing and then only at the very end, insert the data into the controls.